Что делать с ошибкой React.jsx: type is invalid
Использую react-yandex-maps, при коде на главной странице Index.js получаю ошибку

React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <Fragment />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?

сам код главной страницы состоит из
index.js
 import App from './App';
 import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
 import Header  from './component/Header/Header';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
 import React from 'react';

 ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Header/>
    <App />
 </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
 );
 reportWebVitals();

и App.js
import  {YMaps,Map,Placemark } from 'react-yandex-maps';
import Header from './component/Header/Header';

const App = () => {
  return (<>
  <Header/>
  <YMaps query={{load: "package.full", apikey: "68e79bed-1ab0-40d4-8c3f-0f08f945ffce"}}>
  <Map defaultState={{ center: [55.751574, 37.573856], zoom: 9 }}>
    <Placemark defaultGeometry={[55.751574, 37.573856]} />
  </Map>
</YMaps>;
  </>);
};

export default App(); 

Header
import React from 'react';
import './Header.css';


const Header = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="Header-comp-main">
                <section className="Header-comp-tabs">
                    <a href="Map.js">Мемориалы</a>
                    <a href="Pam.js">Памятники</a>
                    <a href="/news">Новости</a>
                    <a href="Strit.js">Улицы</a>
                </section>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;

До этого я перепроверила все компоненты и объявления функции - ничего не работает

Добавьте в вопрос компонет Header

Почему у вас везде есть import React from 'react';, а в App.js нету?


Поменяйте расширения файлов на .jsx
Если вы используете React < 16 версии то добавляйте везде import React from "react";
В компоненте Header уберите тег фрагмента (<></>), он там не нужен
В файле index.jsx не нужен компонент Header судя по его использованию так как он уже есть в App.jsx

